# Goolgebot can't trace / Fetch my Joomla Website

Tags: php, html, joomla, google-search-console, googlebot

Googlebot can't fetch my joomla site after I migrate to another Hosting ..

And when I checked with http://web-sniffer.net/ (with option: Trace., and user-agent: googlebot) the result is 403.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /
on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at www.mentarimedia.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

pls help me for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello  @Evelyn Raditya Mentarimedia,

I think its due to your migration of server. It was like temporary issue. It works fine now. Please check.

Let me know if you are having still an issue with it...

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you need to create or modify the robots.txt in your root directory.

Comment: I migrate to another Hosting .. 
I did not change anything like robots.txt and .htaccess

Comment: Call your hosting company.

Comment: i have call the host company.. until now can't resolve this prob

Comment: It's either got to be the .htaccess or robots.txt. You haven't changed the htaccess but maybe there is a rule in which the path has changed from your old hosting company.

Comment: You have to download joomla package and copy the robots.txt from there to be sure that has the default values.